# Proxy request to specific http using tor\socks

Tags: docker, proxy, telegram-bot, tor

OS: CentOS7

I've got application for telegram api bot in docker. By deafult it sends all requests to https://api.telegram.org (149.154.167.220) which is blocked in my country. This URL variable can't be changed from my side.

I installed tor and curl request is completed successfully

```
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9150 https://api.telegram.org/
```

Which software can I use to force using socks5 for all https requests to above url? Or maybe there is another more suitable option to proxy all this traffic?

Answer (score 1):

It turnes out that docker itself has option to proxy traffic through specific host\port 
https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client

Answer (score 0):

[proxychains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains) is exactly what you are looking for.

> proxychains - a tool that forces any TCP connection made by any given application to follow through proxy like TOR or any other SOCKS4, SOCKS5 or HTTP(S) proxy. Supported auth-types: "user/pass" for SOCKS4/5, "basic" for HTTP.

I assume it works with CentOS, since it is Linux based, but I've never used Cent before.

Comment: I don't think it's gonna work, cause application is running in docker.

```
this program works only on dynamically linked programs. also both proxychains and the program to call must use the same dynamic linker (i.e. same libc)
```